# JSRender modify dispform.aspx button

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, jslink

I want to modify the button, the display text and the url link. How can I do that with JS-Link?

Comment: Of what button? Can you attach a screenshot of what you mean? :)

Comment: Hi, its the cancel button, i fixed it. with adding a cewp in the edit disp form